# om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Im attempting to create 2 tables, but I dont fully understand where Im going wrong. It's obviously a syntax error, and Im new to SQL in general, can someone explain to me what Im doing wrong here?

```
 String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                "uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL," +
                " team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN manager NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (uuid))";

        String query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + secondTableName + " (" +
                "team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " team_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL" +
                " BOOLEAN friendly_fire NOT NULL," +
                " VARCHAR(255) hq," +
                " VARCHAR(255) rally," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (team_name))";
```

This is my stacktrace:

```
WARN com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'manager NOT NULL, BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (uuid))' at line 1
```

Code used to execute:

```
    private void createTables(String tableName, String secondTableName) throws SQLException {
    try {
        checkConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                "uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL," +
                " team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN manager NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (uuid))";

        String query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + secondTableName + " (" +
                "team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " team_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL" +
                " BOOLEAN friendly_fire NOT NULL," +
                " VARCHAR(255) hq," +
                " VARCHAR(255) rally," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (team_name))";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);

        preparedStatement.execute();
        preparedStatement2.execute();
        main.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Tables " + tableName + " and " + secondTableName + " were successfully created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message, as well as which API you are using to execute your SQL queries.

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace and specify the value of `tableName`. Also show the code used to execute.

Comment: I edited my previous post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is presence of `MAX` in the table definition. `VARCHAR` expects a number as an argument so you either need to define `MAX` as variable and pass it (from Java) or just replace `MAX` with a number, e.g.:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                "uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL," +
                " team_name VARCHAR( + " + MAX + ") NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN manager NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (uuid))";
```

OR

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                "uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL," +
                " team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN manager NOT NULL," +
                " BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (uuid))";
```

If you do not know the max length then you can use `LONGTEXT` as type.

Also, we need to fix the ordering of `type` and column names, it needs to be `manager BOOLEAN` and not `BOOLEAN manager`, e.g.:

```
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + " (" +
                "uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL," +
                " team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
                " manager BOOLEAN NOT NULL," +
                " team_chat BOOLEAN NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY (uuid))";

    String query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + secondTableName + " (" +
            "team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL," +
            " team_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL" +
            " friendly_fire BOOLEAN  NOT NULL," +
            " hq VARCHAR(255)," +
            " rally VARCHAR(255)," +
            " PRIMARY KEY (team_name))";
```

Comment: Note that in SQL Server (contrary to MySQL used by OP), `varchar(max)` is a valid datatype definition (it defines a varchar of 'unlimited' size (2^31 -1 bytes)).

Answer (score 0):

The column name has to come before the data type.  So

```
BOOLEAN manager NOT NULL,
BOOLEAN team_chat NOT NULL,
```

should be

```
manager BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
team_chat BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
```